# In simple terms, why does a skateboard slide in the opposite direction of its falling rider?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction, free-body-diagram

I would like to have a better understanding of something I’ve observed:

If I stand on a skateboard at rest, there is no movement.
If I lift my left leg, my body of course starts to fall to the left, the same as if I were on flat ground. My recollection is that this is because my center of balance (probably somewhere around my bellybutton) is no longer above my support base (which is now the bottom of my right foot).
But as I fall left, the skateboard rolls to the right. Why? Why doesn’t it just stay still as my body falls downwards?
thanks!

(illustration follows)

[image: skateboard physics question illustration]

Comment: Do you know Newton's laws of motion? It is simply Newton's third law of motion.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the [law of conservation of momentum,](https://www.britannica.com/science/mechanics/Conservation-of-momentum) one of the basic laws imposed on all physics theories. From zero momentum, there is suddenly momentum in the direction of fall. The board compensates equal and opposite to the created momentum (forgetting frictional forces).

Laws are distillates of observations, so your observation is what made Newton impose axiomatically the [second law of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Second) important in classical mechanics at the time,and is imposed on all physics theories later to get consistent transition between theories modeling observations.

In simple term the answer to this "why" is "because" that is what is always observed and it is made into a law.

Comment: I don't doubt that you're right, but I still don't fully get it. Like, what if there was no skateboard? Does the force that pushed the skateboard just not exist then? And why is the thing that is "conserving momentum" or "providing an equal and opposite reaction" necessarily the skateboard and not something else, like the air around the rider, or the rider's clothes, or the ground, etc. It still feels a bit too abstract and arbitrary to me.